# differences in computation outputs, theano, non theano

Tags: python, numpy, theano

I'm starting to play around with theano, and so I tried computing a simple function and testing the output, however when I test a theano compiled version versus a non theano version the outputs are a bit different....

The code:

```
import numpy as np
import theano.tensor as T
from theano import function

np.random.seed(1)
S = np.random.rand(4,3)
Q = np.random.rand(4,3)

def MSE(a, b):
    n = min(a.shape[0], b.shape[0])
    fhat = T.dvector('fhat')
    y = T.dvector('y')
    mse = ((y - fhat)**2).sum() / n
    mse_f = function([y, fhat], mse)
    return mse_f(a,b)

for row in range(S.shape[0]):
    print(MSE(S[row], Q[row]))

for i in range(S.shape[0]):
    print(((S[i] - Q[i])**2).sum() / S.shape[0])
```

the outputs:

```
# from MSE function
0.0623486922837
0.0652202301174
0.151698460419
0.187325204482

# non theano output
0.0467615192128
0.0489151725881
0.113773845314
0.140493903362
```

What am I over looking here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the expression in this statement

```
    print(((S[i] - Q[i])**2).sum() / S.shape[0])
```

you should divide by `S.shape[1]`, not `S.shape[0]`.

You created `S` using `S = np.random.rand(4,3)`, which means `S` has shape (4, 3).  That is, `S.shape` is `(4, 3)`.    The length of each row in `S` is `S.shape[1]`.

Comment: oh...that is correct. though, now I'm a bit confused as to what is actually happening here. `n` should be equal to 4, which is the same as `S.shape[0]`... OH NO, wait I see, at that point it becomes a row vector and so the shape is simply the length of the row.

Comment: I added an additional comment to the answer.  Does that help?